# Dynamic list elements and pages/dialogues

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a question about jQuery Mobile. The thing is that i use a very long list with dynamic elements loading! When user scrolls to the end of the list, he taps on "load more items" and then another 30 elements are loaded and appended to the existing list. When he taps on an element, a dialog is shown with info,etc! When the user closes the dialog, the list is refreshed and first 30 items are loaded. This is annoying because it's a very long list (~1300 elements).

How can I prevent this happening? Is there a way of parsing parameters from dialog closing button to previous page? Or any suggestions?

PS: I can provide any line of code you want! I didn't put any code for now because I'm not sure which part to post :)!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364424/why-is-jquerymobile-reloading-the-page-on-dialog-close

Comment: i had pageshow there but when i changed to pageload event, the ajax isn't even called on loading!