# jQueryMobile close dialog WITHOUT page refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm attempting to replace JavaScript prompt() function with a jQM dialog. My goal is to prompt the user for a string, then when they submit (submit button or enter), run a function with the string they've entered.

In detail, I want the cancel button and [x] to close the dialog and return to the page, doing nothing; I want the submit button to pass the #strAccount value to a function. This is easy enough to do without a form, etc. However, I also want the user to be able to hit enter while in the #strAccount field. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to make it a form--thus, submit and enter would both submit.

I figured out I need to return false on form submit. However, with doing all of that, the page is reloading, which I do not want.

Here's a bit of the main page content:

```html
 <div id="NewEntry" data-role="page" data-title="New Time Entry">
    <h3>Timesheet </h3>
    <a id="openDialog" data-rel="dialog">Get account name...</a>
 </div>
```

Here's the dialog:

```html
<div id="accountEntry" data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Filter by Account Name</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="acctNameFilter" data-rel="back" data-ajax="false">
            <p>Enter two or more letters from any part of the account name below:</p>
            <input type="text" id="strAccount" placeholder="Enter any part of account name" autocomplete="off">
            <a href="#NewEntry" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true">Cancel</a>
            <input type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my page script:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert('page loading...'); //alert me if page reloads
    $('#acctNameFilter').submit(function()
    {
        alert($('#strAccount').val()); //did it get passed?
        getAcctsByString($('#strAccount').val()); //the function I want to run
        $('#strAccount').val(''); //clear out the dialog's value... (necessary?)
        $('#accountEntry').dialog('close');
        return false; //stop execution, I thought...
    });
     //#openDialog is a simple href link...
    $('#openDialog').click(function()
    {
        $.mobile.changePage('#accountEntry',{changeHash: false});
    });
}
```

Another, less important question: how do I set focus to `#strAccount` after the dialog loads? I want to minimize user presses.

MANY thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm. While working further I noticed that when closing the dialog box, the page was returning to the _previously opened page_. Perhaps the page isn't reloading--it's returning to the previous page!

Comment: It is the similar question to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364424